# unslider is not acting responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently using the unslider and it is not being responsive on my site. I am not exactly sure why it not being responsive because i have it set as fluid.

Code below:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://unslider.com/unslider.min.js"></script>
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.banner').unslider({
            speed: 600,   //Speed in milliseconds
            delay: 4000, // To delay between slide (in milliseconds
            keys: true,
            fluid: true,
            dots: true 

            });
         });
 </script>
```

Do i need to do something in my CSS file or do I need to make my images into %

Thanks!

Below is the HTML:

```
<div class="banner">
    <ul =" col span_6_of_6">
        <li><img src='Images/farmimg1.jpg' width="1000" height="577" alt= "Farm Photo"></li>        
        <li><img src = "Images/tunisewefield.jpg" width="1000" height= "577" alt= "Tunis Ewe in field"></li>
        <li><img src = "Images/barnsimg.jpg"width="1000" height= "577" alt= "Wise Family Sheep Farm"></li>
        <li><img src= "Images/sheepfield.jpg" width= "1000" height = "577" alt= "Sheep in Field"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have relevant HTML ? Or can you create a fiddle link or post site link ?

Comment: <div class="banner">
 <ul =" col span_6_of_6">

  <li><img src='Images/farmimg1.jpg' width="1000" height="577" alt= "Farm Photo"></li>
  <li><img src = "Images/tunisewefield.jpg" width="1000" height= "577" alt= "Tunis Ewe in field"></li>
  <li><img src = "Images/barnsimg.jpg"width="1000" height= "577" alt= "Wise Family Sheep Farm"></li>
  <li><img src= "Images/sheepfield.jpg" width= "1000" height = "577" alt= "Sheep in Field"></li>
 
 </ul>
</div>

Comment: Not put height and width on images

Comment: So i should not but a width or height on my images?

Comment: yes...correct...Don't put any height and width on images inline

Answer (score -1):

As other guys said, best would be to remove width and height from inline images. My suggestion to keep images responsive would be to add responsive class to each image.
Something like this:

```
<li><img class="img-resposive" src='Images/farmimg1.jpg' alt= "Farm Photo"></li>
```

while img-resposive would look like:

```
.img-resposive{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```